# Is there a listener for when a user gets connected to a WiFi network (with internet access)?

Tags: android, listener, wifimanager, android-connectivitymanager

I'm struggling to get to know when a user gets connected to a WiFi network **with Internet access**.

So far, I've tried two ways to achieve that:

- using a `BroadcastReceiver` (action: `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`), and;
- registering a `NetworkCallback` on `ConnectivityManager`.

Both of them fail most of the times since their callbacks are called too soon, because they are called while the network has no Internet access.

Is there a way to achieve what I want (for APIs >= 16)?

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest is to use ConnectivityManager to monitor connectivity status by implementing the following codes

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnected();
```

For more information please check the android Developer guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type)

Comment: Hi, @GeorgeMachibya. Thanks for the contribution, but that is not what the question was asking.